# Azure Protection Policy/ Azure RMS - generic data protection

Tags: azure, types, dataformat, data-protection

I am not sure I fully understand what kind of data can be protected using the tools offered by Azure Protection Policy and Azure RMS.

In particular, I have problem understanding to which extent "non native" data format can benefit from the generic protection. **Does that really apply to any kind of data format ? or is it still restricted to some data types ?**

Thanks in advance for your answer,

Best regards,

Leonard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted that question on one of the [Azure documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/rms-client/client-admin-guide-file-types?hubRefSrc=email&utm_source=lfemail&utm_medium=email)

Here is the answer I got from one of the moderator:

> The data protection service (Azure Rights Management) from Azure Information Protection has the ability to protect all file types.  However, you need an application to do that protection.  The Azure Information Protection client is such an application and has components that include an extension for File Explorer (so that you can right-click a file to protect it), PowerShell (so that you can bulk-protect or script protection of files), and now the scanner (so that a Windows service can inspect the contents of files stored on-premises and automatically protect these files if sensitive data is found).
>
> For the Azure Information Protection client, there are some exceptions for files that it won't protect (see the file types excluded section on this page). You can't currently install this client on Linux, but that's an OS limitation rather than a file type limitation.
>
> In addition to the Azure Information Protection client, other applications and services can interact with the Azure Rights Management service to protect files.  We provide SDKs for software vendors and developers so that their applications and services can protect files - and they choose whether to support native protection only, or also support generic protection.  Applications support specific file types, so it makes sense for them to implement native protection.  Generic protection is good for when you don't know the file type in advance - for example, protecting all files in a folder that contains a mix of file types.  Or, as a software developer, you want to make a single call to protect files and don't need the additional protection that native protection provides (enforcing usage rights, expiry, offline access control).

I hope this will also help some of you guys !

Best regards,

Leonard